# Filter array of multibyte strings ending in a specific letter and conditionally mutate the retained strings

Tags: php, arrays, replace, filtering, multibyte

A now write this function for my script. It works well type but a little slows down. Consider the function and if you have options for optimally ask me to help.

Here is my code:

```
function izada($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if(substr_count($value, "ӣ") == 2) {
            $result[] = str_replace("ӣ ", "ӣ, ", $value);
        }
        if(mb_substr($value, -1) !== "ӣ") {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
        if(substr_count($value, "ӣ") == 2) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
        $array = array_filter(array_unique(array_merge($array, $result)));
    }
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if(substr_count($value, "ӣ") > 2 || substr_count($value, "ӣ") < 1) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Input and function call:

```
$array = array (
  "забони тоҷикӣ",
  "хуҷандӣ бӯстонӣ",
  "Тоҷикистон Ватанам",
  "Ғафуровӣ Мичуринӣ Савхозӣ",
  "Конверторӣ хуруфҳо"
);

$array = izada($array);

echo"<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo"</pre>";
```

Result must be:

```
Array (
  [0] => забони тоҷикӣ
  [1] => хуҷандӣ, бӯстонӣ
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jakub's answer is not optimized and is potentially incorrect according to your posted method.

- It allows the possibility of a value with 2 ӣ's but not ending with ӣ to qualify.  (If this is acceptable, then you should clarify your question requirements.)
- It calls `substr_count()` 1 to 3 times per iteration (depending on conditional outcomes).  The important thing to consider for efficiency is minimizing function calls.

**This is a more accurate / efficient process:**

Method: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XcUJf))

```
foreach ($array as $v) {
    if (mb_substr($v, -1) == "ӣ") {
        if (($count = substr_count($v, "ӣ")) == 1) {
            $result[] = $v;
        } elseif ($count == 2) {
            $result[] = str_replace("ӣ ", "ӣ, ", $v);
        }
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'забони тоҷикӣ',
  1 => 'хуҷандӣ, бӯстонӣ',
)
```

Notice that my method first requires the final character to be `ӣ`, this offers the quickest return without declaring/overwriting `$count` for non-qualifying values.
`$count` is used to cache the result of `substr_count()` for each iteration.  By doing this, the iteration only needs to make the function call once -- improving efficiency.

---

Update, if my earlier snippet is logically correct, it can be refactored to be a single `preg_filter()` call including two replacements (one which needs no comma injection and another which injects a comma) ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/62gO9))

```
var_export(
    preg_filter(
        ['/^[^ӣ]*(?:ӣ(?! ))?[^ӣ]*ӣ$/u', '/^[^ӣ]*ӣ\K [^ӣ]*ӣ$/u'],
        ['$0', ',$0'],
        $array
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

All the `array_merge` and `array_unique` are taking up unnecessary resources. Instead of trying to alter the original array, why not create an output array and fill it with the data you want?

There are also several redundant conditions - you are checking for the same thing several times. From what I understood, this is what you want:

Return all strings where `ӣ` is present once or twice, either at the end or twice anywhere. If it is present twice, add a coma.

So you could simplify it like

```
function izada($array) {
  $ret = [];
  foreach($array as $string){
      if (substr_count($string, "ӣ") >= 1 && substr_count($string, "ӣ") <= 2) {
          if(substr_count($string, "ӣ") == 2) {
              $ret[] = str_replace("ӣ ", "ӣ, ",$string);
          }
          else if (mb_substr($string, -1) == "ӣ") {
              $ret[] = $string;
          }
      }
  }
  return $ret;
```

}

Comment: Thank you! The next time I write functions I will take your advice into account the respected Jakub Judas! :)